# Two color alt text of image formating - Is there a way?

Tags: html, css, inline

Is there a way to change the color of the `alt` text?  I would like to make the `alt` text two different colors. "First" Blue and the "Last" Red?

```
<img id="header-logo" alt="FirstLast" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-family:Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:50px;max-width:50%!important;height:auto!important" width="300" border="0">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9a8grqfx/

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: and why? alt is not meant to be seen. If it's the case you need to fix your images

Comment: alt is considered a fallback for cases when visual info is not available to a user for some reason. It's really weird trying to decorate it visually. Could you elaborate on actual use case for that - in particular, what's alt for in the first place here? If you're trying to safeguard against images that didn't load properly there are other ways.

Comment: No, it is not possible and won't be. For decoration you have `img` not rescue feedback. By the way - why are you declare `color` `text-decoration` `font` etc for `img`? It is an image not a text or input

Comment: I'm using it as a fallback in case the image is blocked in an email and the alt text is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why the `alt` attribute exists is accessibility: If a visually impaired person "views" a website using a screenreader, the text inside the `alt` attribute will be read to the person by the screenreader (or less often by a "Refreshable braille display").

In this case it will definitely *not*  matter at all if that text is blue, red, green, big or small, upside down or whatever - the person to which it is read *won't see* what it looks like. The only thing that matters is that the content of the attribute supplies a good verbal description of the visual content shown by the image (that's what accessibility guidelines require).

So what you are asking for simply would be useless, or maybe even counterproductive if the attribute content isn't desciptive, but tries to perform some visual effect instead.

Comment: I'm using the alt text as a fall back in case the image can not load from an email.

Comment: Also in this situation it needs to be descriptive above everything else (= describe what the image shows).